# Large Number times Tiny Number

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

A (maybe noob) question: Let

```
a = 1234567891234567889998.5
b = 1234567891234567889999.5
```

Mathematica (v8) yields for

```
a*0.5 - b*0.5
```

--> `0.` (wrong answer) and

```
(a - b)*0.5
```

--> `-0.5` (correct answer)

although both expressions `a*0.5 - b*0.5` and `(a - b)*0.5` are mathematically identical. I set `$MinPrecision = 200`, to no avail.

Is there a way to get for both analytically identical expressions the same numerical result? In my original mathematical problem I want to compare two representations of the same problem, with one yielding a vast sum over products of binomial coefficients (yielding numerically results of order `10^2^n`, for `n > 10`) with tiny numbers (order `0.1^2^n`). Analytically I cannot simplify the expressions.

Thanks a bunch.

Michelle

Comment: By using `0.5`, you lose the advantages of arbitrary precision, since `0.5` is a *machine precision* number. Why not divide the quantities by `2` instead?

Comment: Actually 0. is not a wrong answer. Welcome to numerics.

Comment: @MichelleRudolph Welcome to Mma.SE!  I've formatted the code in your post.  You can look at what I did (and fix anything).  In the toolbar above the editing window, there is a button to format selected text.  Or you can use backticks for inline code and indent 4 spaces for code blocks.

Comment: I'm curious, where do numbers like `1234567891234567889998.5` come from?  I mean, is it a real application?  Or is it specifically a test of precision?

Comment: Hey Mark. No, it was just an example, nothing more. The real problem has much stranger numbers (along the line of sums over products of binomial coefficients, where the summation runs over partitions of integers) ... trying to formulate some crazy relations we came up with. Again, cheers for your response!

Comment: The _classic_ example of this is entering `1E12 + 1 - 1E12` on a ten digit calculator, and it can show up in unexpected ways in numerics.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the precision of `a` and `b` are set by the form of their input.

```
a = 1234567891234567889998.5; b = 1234567891234567889999.5;
Precision[a]
```

> ```
> 22.0915
> ```

And `0.5` by default has `MachinePrecision`, these days typically `Log10[2^53]` or just under 16 digits.

```
Precision[0.5]
```

> ```
> MachinePrecision
> ```

Neither setting the precision of `0.5` to `200` or dividing by the exact number `2` fixes the precision of `a` or `b`:

```
a*0.5`200 - b*0.5`200
```

> ```
> -0.*10^-1
> ```

```
a/2 - b/2
```

> ```
> -0.*10^-1
> ```

*Edit:* I should probably point out that the funny output `-0.*10^-1` means less than one digit of precision with the first nonzero digit in the tenths place.

```
a/2 - b/2 // FullForm
```

> ```
> -0.5`0.6989700043360207
> ```

Set the precision to be as much more than `b` as needed or desired.  Let's try one more digit.

```
extra = 1;
prec = Ceiling[Log10[1234567891234567889999.5]] + extra
```

> ```
> 23
> ```

```
a = SetPrecision[1234567891234567889998.5, prec];
b = SetPrecision[1234567891234567889999.5, prec];

a*SetPrecision[0.5, prec] - b*SetPrecision[0.5, prec]
Precision[%]
```

> ```
> -0.5
> 1.30643
> ```

We see we end up with slight more than `extra` digits of precision.

---

Alternatively, you could enter `a` and `b` with explicit precision:

```
a = 1234567891234567889998.5`30;
b = 1234567891234567889999.5`30;

a * 0.5`30 - b * 0.5`30
```

> ```
> -0.50000000
> ```

Comment: Thanks a great bunch, Michael. You detailed answer really helped! I appreciate very much!

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary precision can be a tricky thing, particularly when you start to mix numbers at various levels of precision.  As the was pointed out in the comments, if you mix quantities Mathematica will coerce the results to be of the lower precision.  For example:

```
{Sin[Pi/4], Sin[0.25 Pi]}
(* Out: {1/Sqrt[2], 0.707107} *)
```

Note that `Sin[Pi/4]` returns the *infinite* precision number `1/Sqrt[2]` while `Sin[0.25Pi]` returns the *machine* precision number $0.707107$.  In your case, your mixing *machine* precision (the `0.5`) with *arbitrary* precision (the long `a` and `b`).  Let's check the intermediate expressions.

```
a = 1234567891234567889998.5;
b = 1234567891234567889999.5;
{a*0.5, b*0.5, a*0.5 - b*0.5, (a - b) 0.5}

(* Out: {6.17284*10^20, 6.17284*10^20, 0., -0.5} *)
```

Now you can see clearly what's happened.

Since I started typing, I notice that Michael E2 has already pointed out that `(a-b)/2` yields a strange result due to the insufficient precision to express the result and also mentioned that `SetPrecision` can be used to improve the situation.  Let me also mention a more compact way to enter this:

```
1234567891234567889998.5`30;
b = 1234567891234567889999.5`30;
(a - b)/2

(* Out: -0.50000000 *)
```

Have fun!!

Comment: Thanks Mark for the quick answer. All your suggestions helped very much. It's working now (my little test), and now on to solving the real problem (which gonna require some rewriting of my script along your suggestions). ;-)